# Laravel Many To Many Relation and Model

Tags: php, database, laravel, frameworks, database-relations

I have the following trouble.. I want to create form with binding to model.

My tables structure:

```
Table "Pages"
- id
- isHidden
- isDeleted

Table "Contents"
- id
- title
- content

Table "Seo"
- id
- title
- description
- keywords

Table "Contents_Pages"
- page_id
- content_id
- language_id

Table "Contents_Seo"
- page_id
- seo_id
```

Models structure

```
Model "Page"
public function content() {
    return $this->belongsToMany('Content');
}

Model "Content"
public function seo() {
    return $this->belongsToMany('Seo');
}
```

How to create it in one form, in view?

Comment: why you want so many table you can create one table and put all these columns in it. if it is single language.

Comment: you can use blog_post table as example from this schema design http://www.laravelsd.com/share/s4UjqE

Comment: Hmm.. okey, i changed my tables structure, but question is still actual - how can i bind form to model, with automatically filled fields?

Comment: {{ Form::model($pageModel, array('route' => array('admin.page.update'))) }}
{{ Form::text('alias', NULL, ); }}
{{ Form::close() }} - This alias field fill automatically..

Comment: you field name should be same as column name in database table if you have column name email then you text field should be same name {{ Form::text('email', ); }}

Comment: check this video will help you more http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EJwxG3b9j9c